# Looking for a jQuery + AJAX + PHP5/PDO + MySQL Recordset Pagination Widget

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, widget

Before I go off and spend several hours building this, I wanted to see if anyone had found a jQuery/AJAX pagination recordset widget that did this:

1. Is framework agnostic. Doesn't rely on CodeIgniter, Kohana, or anything like that. Just give it PHP5 and PDO for MySQL and a MySQL database and off it goes. (Of course, you would have to configure the jQuery component to tie it to the proper variables.)
2. Supports a query even on a JOIN.
3. Doesn't store SQL statements on the client. Keeps it on the server.
4. Tries to prevent XSS by using prepared statements and other tactics.
5. Supports resortable columns.
6. Hover over a row and it highlights the row.
7. Alternates colors of each row in odd/even pattern.
8. Click a row and it triggers an event with the value of the first column of a given SQL query, which is a hidden column when displayed.
9. Shows the usual First, Prev, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Next, Last buttons in the bottom right of the widget. If you go past 5, it then centers the number like 4 5 6 7 8 where 6 would be selected, and so on, where possible until the end of the pagination.
10. Is easily styled with CSS.
11. Works via jQuery and AJAX back to a single PHP page that manages the widget.
12. Each click on the component does not redirect the page. Instead, as one paginates, it reloads the component over AJAX. (One could, however, intercept the record-click event and make it do something.)

A typical scenario would be that you create a DIV on a page, use jQuery to assign it as an ajaxRecordset(), and then inside ajaxRecordset() you would use {} to assign options for that recordset. However, no SQL queries would be stored on the front end. The widget would talk back to a single PHP page over AJAX which would receive a query number and then would use that query with given variables like v1, v2, v3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using jquery, [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is a useful plugin I used on a project last summer that accomplishes most of what you listed.